# Как скачать файл по URL с именем, предоставленным сервером, с помощью DownloadManager?

Tags: android

API предоставляет мне URL файлов в таком виде:

```
https://some.server.com/some/path/with/hash/23neo23ij2eo2i3eno2n3e
```

по этой ссылке предполагается скачивание файла с названием, например, `real_name.txt`

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
```

`DownloadManager.Request` заставляет меня указывать имя, с которым будет сохранен файл в дефолтной папке загрузок. Но я не знаю название файла)

Есть какой-то способ заставить `DownloadManager` использовать имя файла, предоставляемое сервером в заголовках в момент загрузки?